# Internationlization Java

Tags: java, internationalization, date-formatting

Is there way to overwrite the default values for internationalization?

Example if I get the date in EEEE format it will give me **Sunday** but I want something like **Sunnyday**.

`"EEEE, dd MMM, yyyy"` gives me Sunday, 27 Mar, 2011

i want `"EEEE, dd MMM, yyyy"` give me Sunnyday, 27 Mar, 2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings used by DateFormat are defined by an object of class `DateFormatSymbols`, which has `setXXX` methods. So you could try this:

```
 DateFormatSymbols englishSymbols = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
 DateFormatSymbols mySymbols = (DateFormatSymbols)englishSymbols.clone();
 String[] weekdays = mySymbols.getWeekdays();
 weekdays[Calendar.SUNDAY] = "Sunnyday";
 mySymbols.setWeekdays(weekdays);
 DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMM, yyyy", mySymbols);

 System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

It shows for me:  `Sunnyday, 27 Mar, 2011`.

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly what I wanted. A small correction to your code.  DateFormatSymbols mySymbols = (DateFormatSymbols)englishSymbols.clone();

Comment: @Viren: Ah, thanks for the correction. I only tried this with Beanshell, which uses a more dynamic typing and does not need the cast.

Answer (score 1):

You must set locale, this is example for France:

```
Locale frLocale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMM yy", frLocale);
Date today = new Date();
String output = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:
dimanche 27 mars 11

Or if you want have own names:

```
String[] monthNames = {"cold January", "warm February" ...};     
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String month = monthName[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)];     
System.out.println("Month name: " + month);
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but what I want is to change the values. 'dimanche' to 'sumthing-else'

Comment: Thanks smas, but what i want is different. I want to change the i18n value from the source. "EEEE, dd MMM, yyyy" should give me Sunnyday, 27 Mar, 2011

Comment: you want to change name of Sunday only or others days too? It must be for every locales or must be locals dependent (for en sunday->sunnyday, for pl sunday->niedziela etc.)?

Comment: Do you know from where Java reads these values? so that I can overwrite that file.

Comment: Java doesn't read this values from files if you want do this you must read your own implementation based on monthNames example. Just change monthNames to dayNames and Calendar.MONTH to Calendar.DAY